# Mixing Razor and Knockout syntax in data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I am trying to mix ASP.NET MVC Razor and Knockout syntax like this:

```
<a data-bind="text: CityName, attr: { href: /search/ + 'CityName' + '/@CurrentCategory}">
</a>
```

Where `CityName` is a knockout property and `@CurrentCategory` is an asp.net mvc property.

Visual Studio gives me an error about syntax.
Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: Can you please clarify what HTML you expect as result?

Comment: You will need to supply more information about the error in order to trouble shoot.  It is possible to mix razor with any client side script you will just need to make sure you escape it correctly.  One pattern I use is @Html.Raw(). Give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
<a data-bind="text: CityName, attr: { href: '/search/' + CityName + '/@CurrentCategory' }">
</a>
```

You need to enclose the static or literal part of the string with `'`s and not the variable, or the dynamic part.

Also make sure you escape any `'`s in any fragment inserted by Razor. The above could be rewritten in order to achieve it as such:

```
<a data-bind="text: CityName, attr: { href: '/search/' + CityName + '/@CurrentCategory.Replace("'", "''")' }">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to know the error to be able to help you accurately 
meanwhile you could try using a computed observable, so in your knockout controller create:

```
self.Url = ko.computed(function(){
   return '/search/' + self.CityName() + '/@CurrentCategory';
});
```